# Code optimisation using numpy array. Is there a better solution?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to optimise a function that calculates : ***a*exp(b*x)+c***

I tested three methods using numpy arrays :

```
def model(a,b,c,x):
    return a*np.exp(b*x)+c
def myFoo1(modelParam,x):
    return([model(*i,x) for i in modelParam])

def myFoo2(modelParam,x):
    return([i[0]*np.exp(i[1]*x)+i[2] for i in modelParam])

def myFoo3(modelParam,x):
    return(np.exp(np.outer(modelParam[:,1],x))*params[:,0][:,None]+params[:,2][:,None])
```

When running time is measured :

```
x=np.array(np.arange(0,100,0.1))
params=np.array([[10,0.1,2],[20,0.3,4],[30,0.2,6],[15,0.2,4],[16,0.5,7]])
%time myFoo1(params,x)
%time myFoo2(params,x)
%time myFoo3(params,x)
```

The output is :

```
CPU times: user 3.58 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 3.58 ms
Wall time: 2 ms
CPU times: user 855 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 855 µs
Wall time: 703 µs
CPU times: user 690 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 690 µs
Wall time: 564 µs
```

The first one was my original code because it is easiest to program. But, the third one is 4 times faster. Can I improve it again ?

And with %timeit (question edited as suggested in comment):

```
211 µs ± 663 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
199 µs ± 199 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
164 µs ± 56.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Will you please show a small sample of `modelParam`?

Comment: @user17242583. It is the np.array `params`. There are five examples of a,b,c parameters.

Comment: I meant, will you please show a sample of its contents? It would be easier to experiment with it if I see what it is. Or maybe just its just and the range of the numbers it contains?

Comment: @usrer17242588. I am trying to optimize the call to the function that returns a.exp(b.x)+c for many (a,b,c) parameters set. The x imput is always the same range from 0 to 100 in this example.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Will you please send the result of `print(params.shape)`?

Comment: @user17242583. As `params=np.array([[10,0.1,2],[20,0.3,4],[30,0.2,6],[15,0.2,4],[16,0.5,7]])`, the result is (5,3).

Comment: This is strange: the first takes 46 us, the second 40 us and the third 33 us on my machine (using `timeit`). 2 ms seems huge for such a small input.

Comment: Use timeit instead of time. The former will run the line multiple times and give you insight into the distribution of times you get. Time only runs the line once, which is not as useful when benchmarking.

Comment: @jakub. I edited my question to add %timeit benchmarks

Comment: @Jérôme Richard. I am going to try it on another machine.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is your the processor you used for the benchmark?

Answer (score 2):

I got small improvement by using slightly different way of broadcasting

```
def myFoo4(modelParam,x):
    return modelParam[:, 0:1] * np.exp(modelParam[:, 1:2] * x) + modelParam[:, 2:3]
```

And another small improvement by switching to `np.float32`

```
    x_float32 = np.array(np.arange(0, 100, 0.1), dtype=np.float32)
    params_float32 = np.array([[10, 0.1, 2], [20, 0.3, 4], [30, 0.2, 6], [15, 0.2, 4], [16, 0.5, 7]],
                      dtype=np.float32)
```

```
    41       100      17042.0    170.4     19.7          myFoo3(params, x)
    42       100      15282.0    152.8     17.6          myFoo4(params, x)
    43       100      11322.0    113.2     13.1          myFoo4(params_float32, x_float32)
```

Comment: It appear that the `np.exp` call is the bottleneck of the computation on my machine as it takes 80% of the time. So I doubt there is a much faster solution (unless the OP accept to use approximations). Just for information: the `np.exp` function does not yet use SIMD instruction on most machines. AFAIK, only processors supporting AVX-512 (eg. Intel Icelake processors) actually use SIMD instructions for this operation resulting in a huge speed-up (about x10 according to Intel).

Comment: @JérômeRichard. How did you profile it ? With %prun ? I could not manage to do that.

Comment: @JérômeRichard You are right, on my machine `np.exp` is also the bottleneck. Thank you about information about SIMD and np.exp, didn't know that. As for faster solution - I though maybe some parallelism (numba/multiprocessing) could speed things up.

Comment: @Stef1611 I used a very low-level profiling tool to find that: `perf` (only on Linux). To check that I just tried to remove everything except the `np.exp` call and it was taking 80% of the time ;) .

Comment: @dankal444 Multiprocessing could be a good idea if there is enough data to compute but the current input is too small for threads to be useful (the time to create threads will likely be significantly bigger). Still, the OP may actually need to compute bigger inputs so it may worth it.

Comment: @JérômeRichard. Concerning the machine = 4 * AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6176. (ie 48 CPU cores). But, for the moment, I use only one core.

Comment: @Stef1611 Ok. Thank you. The gap in performance is partially justified by the frequency with is 2 time higher on my machine and the fact that this  processor appear not to support fused-multiply-add instructions generally used by the computation of the exponential. One way to speed up this would be to use the Intel version of Anaconda provided with the SVML library which *may* vectorize `np.exp` calls on AMD's Opterons (I am not sure it is free though). Otherwise, using more cores with a bigger input or using an approximation seems the only way to speed up that.

Comment: @JérômeRichard. Thanks for all these useful informations. I did profiling of each step and, as you found, 80% of time is used to calculate np.exp.